# How can Draggable Views be used in columns?

Tags: blocks, panels, javascript, views

I have a content type in which I would like to be able to have a 3 column layout and the user is able to drag different content (nodes/blocks) from one column to another, inline. I have almost achieved this with Panels IPE but there are two main problems:

1. Users with IPE access have access to the IPE "Add Content" modal, and therefore access to all content on the site, I would need to restrict this somehow
2. The user experience is not exactly inline/in place, because when clicking customize the page changes quite significantly, I have tried modifying this via CSS but it only gets so far

I experimented with [Draggable Views](https://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) since and it solved both of the issues above, but it created a new problem. I cannot find a way to be able to drag View items from one column to another column, for example dragging a block from the left side bar to the right side bar. I have tried this using Panels and Draggable Views, but it only allows dragging inside one column. The closest module that I have found that has this functionality is [JQuery Drag Drop Blocks module](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_drag_drop) but it doesn't have a working D7 version. Is there a way that this can be done?